# What is the SQL used to create the Running Vusers graph in LoadRunner Analysis?

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, performance-testing, loadrunner

In HP LoadRunner Analysis, there is a running vusers graph that shows the current number of virtual users that are running throughout the test. An example graph is shown below.

[image: Running VUsers Graph]

Does anyone know what is the SQL used to create the data for this graph? I know the data is stored in the LoadRunner analysis MDB database directly? ie An_Session1.mdb, though I am unable to determine the SQL Query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refined the query a bit so I post a new answer instead of editing the previous one.

This produces columns that contain the CUMULATIVE count of vusers for a specific action over time. Please note that the output is not linear, it only contains a row when something has happened (x-axis).

```
SELECT
 M.[End Time] AS RelTimeSec, 
 M.[VUser ID] AS VuserID,  
 M.[VUser Status ID] AS StatusID, 
 S.[Vuser Status Name],
 ( SELECT 
     Count( VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID] )
   FROM 
     VuserEvent_Meter 
   WHERE 
     VuserEvent_Meter.[InOut Flag]=1 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[End Time]<=M.[End Time] AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser ID]>0 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID]=1
 ) AS CumulReady,
( SELECT 
     Count( VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID] )
   FROM 
     VuserEvent_Meter 
   WHERE 
     VuserEvent_Meter.[InOut Flag]=1 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[End Time]<=M.[End Time] AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser ID]>0 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID]=2
 ) AS CumulRun,
( SELECT 
     Count( VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID] )
   FROM 
     VuserEvent_Meter 
   WHERE 
     VuserEvent_Meter.[InOut Flag]=1 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[End Time]<=M.[End Time] AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser ID]>0 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID]=3
 ) AS CumulPause,
 ( SELECT 
     Count( VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID] )
   FROM 
     VuserEvent_Meter 
   WHERE 
     VuserEvent_Meter.[InOut Flag]=1 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[End Time]<=M.[End Time] AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser ID]>0 AND
     VuserEvent_Meter.[VUser Status ID]=4
 ) AS CumulQuit

FROM
 VuserEvent_Meter M 
INNER JOIN 
 VuserStatus S ON M.[VUser Status ID] = S.[Vuser Status ID]
WHERE
  M.[InOut Flag]=1 AND M.[VUser Status ID] IN (1,2,3,4) AND M.[VUser ID]>0
ORDER BY
 M.[End Time]
```

Outputs something like:

```
RelTimeSec  VuserID StatusID    Vuser Status Name   CumulReady  CumulRun    CumulPause  CumulQuit
  15    1   2   Run     1   1   0   0
  15    1   1   Ready   1   1   0   0
  30    2   2   Run     2   2   0   0
  30    2   1   Ready   2   2   0   0
  45    3   1   Ready   3   3   0   0
  45    3   2   Run     3   3   0   0
  60    4   2   Run     4   4   0   0
  60    4   1   Ready   4   4   0   0
  75    5   1   Ready   5   5   0   0
  75    5   2   Run     5   5   0   0
  90    6   2   Run     6   6   0   0
  90    6   1   Ready   6   6   0   0
...
1687    88  4   Quit    82  82  0   19
1687    86  4   Quit    82  82  0   19
1687    85  4   Quit    82  82  0   19
1687    87  4   Quit    82  82  0   19
1697    113 2   Run     83  83  0   19
1697    113 1   Ready   83  83  0   19
1712    114 1   Ready   84  84  0   19
1712    114 2   Run     84  84  0   19
1727    115 1   Ready   85  85  0   19
1727    115 2   Run     85  85  0   19
1742    116 2   Run     86  86  0   19
1742    116 1   Ready   86  86  0   19
1747    89  4   Quit    86  86  0   23
```

Comment: Thanks K, This is exactly the start I needed. I was able to get a cumulative running series by subtracting the quit from the running, and by aggregating the data, I have been able to reproduce the trend line in my initial graph exactly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the analysed results in this case.

If you open the .mdb file and have a look at the "VuserEvent_meter" table you will find all the needed data there.

It references the VuserStatus table for what the exact event was. Here's the SQL (written in Access):

```
SELECT
 [M.End Time] AS RelTimeSec, [M.VUser ID] AS VuserID,  [M.VUser Status ID] AS StatusID
FROM
 VuserEvent_Meter M 
WHERE
  [M.InOut Flag]=1 AND [M.VUser Status ID]>0 AND [M.VUser ID]>0
ORDER BY
 [M.End Time]
```

If you want to include the actual event name then you need to JOIN the [VuserStatus.Vuser Status Name] column, based on the [M.VUser Status ID] = [VuserStatus.Vuser Status ID].

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks K, though unfortunately this SQL produces an ever increasing line graph, rather than the trend shown in the image above. Any other ideas?

Comment: For the 3 output columns the 1st is ever incresing yeas, since it's the TIME the event happened.

Comment: It was actually not just the time that keeps expanding, though now thanks to your answer below, it makes more sense. Thanks again for your help.