# create a report with database load runner

Tags: load, runner

i view the document of [What is the SQL used to create the Running Vusers graph in LoadRunner Analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221424/what-is-the-sql-used-to-create-the-running-vusers-graph-in-loadrunner-analysis)
i do the same table in business object but i would like to know how to have a number of vuser , and i have a another probleme when i import the result of my analysis session in sql server i descover that the name of database session in file_>session information change each time i open the session 
if you know plz can i have a single name like that i can work in a single database 
thanks
haddaj

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Event_Meter] table and the related fields for virtual user.   The related tables are in the [Metadata] table.   You should be able to run a graph off of the [Event_Meter] table to generate any graph you want.

if you want to pick up speed, then be sure to create an index on all of the key fields in [Event_Meter] and related tables.